# ngInfiniteScroll Scroll not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to use the nginfiniteScroll from https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/tree/1.0.0. I am able to read it all but I am having some issues in triggering the scroll. When I create a container for the scroll box, the infinite scroll works fine. But when I remove it from a container, and just use a body I don't see it able to scroll. I created a plunkr of my code but it seems to work completely fine in the plunkr, which makes me really confused.

In my own code I have something like so

```
<style>#list-wrapper{
max-height: 400px;
overflow-y: scroll;

margin-top: 20px;
border: solid 1px black;
 }

 h4{
padding: 20px;
 }</style>

<div class="panel-content" data-ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">

<div>
    <div class="list" infinite-scroll='loadMore()'
         infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
        <div class="header">
        </div>
        <div class="list-table">
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in infiniteList">
                        <td style="width:100%">
                            <div>{{item}}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style='clear: both;'></div>
    </div>
</div>

<h4>{{scrollTriggered}}</h4>
</div>
```

and my script

```
 .controller("DashboardCtrl", ["$scope",
function ($scope) {

$scope.infiniteList = [];
$scope.incr = 1;

$scope.scrollTriggered = "";

$scope.loadMore = function () {

    $scope.scrollTriggered += "\n Scroll Triggered"
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        $scope.infiniteList.push("Item " + $scope.incr);
        $scope.incr += 1;
    }
};
 }
 ])
```

Which ends up looking as so [image] and does not trigger the scroll function which is shown in my plunkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/c29ZcoofTqgPXoRpmFbk?p=preview

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: check you code, which may have error to retrieve data and adding into array

Comment: I have updated my question with the appropriate script. As you can see it is the same script as the plunkr for testing purposes. The plunkr doesn't work either from the looks of it.

Comment: add $scope.apply() end of your code

Comment: I see it working in the plunkr but in my code it gives me the $digest already in progress error which I can see why. Also right now shows 90 entries with 3 scroll triggers and doesn;t give the infinite scroll feature.

Answer (score 1):

So this was apparently is a weird answer since it really didn't cross my mind. Because I have a google maps that is full page, I used the .html tag that was

```
.html{
height 100%;
}
```

This caused some errors as it would trigger the scroll at all. Therefore I couldn't scroll at all. Removing the height restriction allowed it to scroll.